# NHibernate ternary association with multiple values - how to map in a nice way

Tags: nhibernate, orm, associations, ternary, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I've asked a similar question, but I've given up on the idea I had there to solve this problem so I would like some help solving this in a neat way instead.

I've got tables

```
Image - (Id, Name, RelativeFilePath)
ImageFilter - (Id, Type)
ImageContext - (Id, Name, ...)
ImageContextImage - (Id, ImageContextId, ImageId, ImageFilterId)
```

Example of data:

```
ImageContextImage      Id        ImageContextId         ImageId        ImageFilterId
                       1         1                      1              1
                       2         1                      1              2
                       3         2                      1              1
                       4         3                      2              1
```

As you can see, an image in a context can have several filters applied.

All of my entities are very simple, except this mapping of the above. Currently I've got

```
ImageContext
    public virtual int Id
    public virtual string Name
    public virtual IList<ImageContextImage> Images

ImageContextImage
    public virtual int Id
    public virtual ImageContext Context
    public virtual Image Image
    public virtual ImageFilter ImageFilter
```

The above is very easy to map, but for each image I then get multiple ImageContextImage objects. I would rather have ImageContextImage contain a list of ImageFilter, so that I can simply iterate through that collection. I've tried alot of permutations of AsTernaryAssociation() and it complains that I need a Dictionary, but I want multiple values per key! Any ideas?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you change the database schema (e.g. add tables, columns, etc...)?

Comment: @Jakub Well, to a certain degree. An ImageFilter has to be able to be added to multiple Images and ImageContexts. Do you have any ideas then? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ternary association can be replaced with binary associations but a new entity will appear after the replacement ([Removing Ternary relationship types](http://www.databasedesign.co.uk/bookdatabasesafirstcourse/chap3/chap3.htm)). It is ImageContextImage entity in your case and the hard part is to find best name for such entity. Your example is very close to this replacement.

ImageContextImage entity:

```
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
public virtual ImageContext Context { get; set; }
public virtual IList<ImageFilter> Filters { get; set; }
```

and it's mapping:

```
Id(x => x.Id);
References(x => x.Image);
References(x => x.Context);
HasManyToMany(x => x.Filters); // filters are referenced via many-to-many relation
```

ImageContext entity:

```
public virtual int Id { get; set; }
public virtual string Name { get; set; }
public virtual IList<ImageContextImage> ImageContextImageList { get; set; }
```

and it's mapping:

```
Id(x => x.Id);
Map(x => x.Name);
HasMany(x => x.ImageContextImageList)
    .Inverse(); // to aggregate all ImageContextImage that are fererencing this instnstance of ImageContext
    .KeyColumn("Context_id");
```

Corresponding database schema is slightly different:

```
ImageContextImage(Id, Image_id, Context_id)
```

and new association table must be created for the many-to-many relation:

```
ImageFilterToImageContextImage(ImageContextImage_id, ImageFilter_id)
```

Note that this is only a sketch of one possible approach. Many details depends on your problem domain and must be tweaked before it is ready for production:) - e.g.cascades.

I have never used AsTernaryAssociation but it seems interesting. I will investigate it later, thank you for the inspiration:).

EDIT:
Ternary association can be implemented by slightly different mapping (using composite-element) but there is still additional entity - ImageContextImage which is mapped as component in this case:

```
public class ImageContext
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ImageContextImage> ImageContextImageList { get; set; }

    public ImageContext()
    {
        ImageContextImageList = new List<ImageContextImage>();
    }
}

public class ImageContextMap : ClassMap<ImageContext>
{
    public ImageContextMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasMany(x => x.ImageContextImageList).Component(c =>
        {
            c.References(x => x.Image);
            c.References(x => x.Filter);
        }).Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}

public class ImageContextImage
{
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
    public virtual ImageFilter Filter { get; set; }
}
```

ImageContext class can be extended by these methods to make things simpler:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Image> AssociatedImages
{
    get
    {
        return ImageContextImageList.Select(x => x.Image).Distinct().ToList();
    }
}

public virtual IEnumerable<ImageFilter> GetFilters(Image image)
{
    return ImageContextImageList.Where(x => x.Image == image).Select(x => x.Filter).ToList();
}
```

No success with AsTernaryAssociation.

Comment: Hey, thanks! Alot of interesting things in there... Will need to peruse it in peace before I decide which approach to take, but I think I can get on the right track. :)